Do I need to provide an EU-compliant privacy policy link for my personal website, which is accessible globally?
Here's a question, let's say you build a website that integrates Google analysis and is accessed by users in the US, and you provide a privacy policy link that complies with domestic law. However, since the website is accessible worldwide, some people from the European Union may also visit your website, but your privacy policy does not comply with EU law, are you in violation of EU law? Will you be penalized by the EU?

Do you have subsidiaries based in Europe?

No. My site is a blog, for posting articles only.@nick012000

are you commercial or not?

This question is similar to: Do hidden service websites require ToS and other legal documents?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Trish the linked question is about the anonymous provisioning of services. This question seems to be more about the GDPR's territorial scope, based on the common misunderstanding that GDPR protects EU citizens whatever they do. An answer of this question would likely focus on a discussion of Art 3 GDPR, in particular on the absence of any targeting intention for Art 3(1)(a).

Not enough information
Article 3(2) of the GDPR tells us when it applies to controllers or processors not based in the EU.

This Regulation applies to the processing of personal data of data subjects who are in the Union by a controller or processor not established in the Union, where the processing activities are related to:
(a) the offering of goods or services, irrespective of whether a payment of the data subject is required, to such data subjects in the Union; or
(b) the monitoring of their behaviour as far as their behaviour takes place within the Union.

Assuming the website is not for personal or household use, then if you do either of those things, you need to comply with the GDPR if you collect personal data.

My website is integrated with Google analytics, is this in accordance with clause b? I don't collect user data myself, Google analytics collects it on its own.

@jiemarleo no, you collect the data - you just use Google analytics to do it. You are the controller, Google is a processor. If the data you collect monitors the activities of Europeans in Europe, you have to comply with the GDPR.
